# Can NodeJS get Grpc Service's response header?

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

We use NodeJS grpc client, and in the server we put some informations to header, so can NodeJS grpc client get the header from the server?

Comment: can you please describe how do you put headers?

Answer (score 2):

Any kind of method call on a client returns a call object. This call object is an event emitter, and it emits the event "metadata" with the initial response metadata (a.k.a. headers). So you just have to listen for that event to get the metadata:

```
var call = client.methodName(arguments);
call.on('metadata', function(metadata){
  // process metadata
}
```

The metadata object you see here is an instance of [the Metadata class](https://grpc.io/grpc/node/grpc.Metadata.html).